# Facebook not able to analyse my web pages to determine useful images etc for shared links

Tags: facebook, html, debugging, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to ensure that meaningful information is supplied with Facebook shared links to the HTML5 pages on my website.  Right now, links are just showing up as a URL, with no description or accompanying image.

I have been using the open graph tags to provide metadata on the page.

I have been trying to check the pages on the website using the [Facebook debugging tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) but the tool does not get any data from the page being checked.

For example, I try to debug the page: http://www.gaiaguide.info/do/Hierarchy
It responds with the error: "Could not retrieve data from URL."

The graph API data provided by the debugging tool has the following value:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1
   }
}
```

When I look at what Facebook scraper sees for the page, all I get is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
```

The entire HTML content is missing.  What is even more peculiar is that it is not even the same doctype as the page I am trying to test.

It is not clear to me why an OAuthException would be raised.  The page is visible to external sources for validation.  For example, I have validated the page on an HTML5 validation site and it is definitely seeing the entirety of the page contents.

I haved tried URLs from other sites served on the same IP address from the same server and they are fine.  An appropriate image and summary is provided in the set of information that would be used to construct the shared link.

I have found other HTML5 pages that validate fine on the Facebook debugger.

I have tried to remove the og:* meta tags from the pages to see if they were causing Facebook to think that the website should be requiring some kind of user authentication but that has not impacted upon the problem.

I have tried to remove the "sharethis.com" mark-up and Javascript that is responsible for the sharing icons to the pages but that has also had no effect.

Any insights into what should be a simple problem would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Geoff S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue I can see on your page is the empty space at the top of your HTML code. I made a copy of your page (http://www.webniraj.com/hierarchy.html) and put it through the debugger after removing the odd characters at the beginning of the file.

The page seemed to work correctly after that:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webniraj.com%2Fhierarchy.html

Comment: Yes - I think you are onto the problem.  I have not been able to determine where those characters come from in the page generation process but I have been able to work with two simpler files on the site, one with the odd characters and one without.  The one without them works fine from my server.  The trouble seems to be with the insertion of U+0000 characters.  I guess figure out how to eliminate them will be the next challenge.

Comment: Cool. Glad I could be of help.